# PLS Structural equation modelling

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

In PLS structural equation modelling when dealing with the outer model (relationship between latent variable and its items) if there is a variable which does not meet the quality criteria should I delete it, or should I  only delete a latent variable when dealing with the inner model (relationship between variables).